# How to check for the last element with an attribute?

Tags: xslt

I have an xml like this:

```
<xml>
    <node name="1">node1</node>
    <node name="2">node2</node>
    <node name="3">node3</node>
    <node>node4</node>
</xml>
```

How do I check that `<node name="3">node3</node>` is the last node with a `@name` attribute?

Comment: @GungFoo, Oh, come on. I tried `position() = last()` but this seems to check for the last node of the kind. Testing for `test="./@name[position() = last()]"` doesn't work as well.

Comment: you generally talk about XML and like leoPark asked in his answer... what are you even using to try and parse this XML? please read the FAQ on how to ask a question. :)

Comment: @GungFoo, Please, be more attentive. The tag states quite clear it's `XSL`.

Comment: The tags aren't just for getting your question answered but also so that people searching in the future have an easier time finding these questions. It's also the reason why a fully fledged question is preferred, with input, "whatyouhavetried.com" and what an acceptable correct answer would look like.

You should work just as hard writing your question as someone would have to answer it. This helps the people willing to answer your question and people who come across it in the future.

Then again, I shouldn't have to explain this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could make use of the **following-sibling** operator here. Assuming you were positioned on a **node** elemenet, you just need to check the current node has an **name** attribute but no following-sibling does

```
<xsl:if test="@name and not(following-sibling::node[@name])">
```

This could also be done as part of a template match

```
<xsl:template match="node[@name][not(following-sibling::node[@name])]">
```

For example, try the following XSLT

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

    <xsl:template match="node[@name][not(following-sibling::node[@name])]">
        <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:attribute name="last">1</xsl:attribute>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <xsl:template match="@*|node()">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When applied to your XML, the following is output

```
<xml>
   <node name="1">node1</node>
   <node name="2">node2</node>
   <node last="1" name="3">node3</node>
   <node>node4</node>
</xml>
```

EDIT: Actually, in a template match, you could make use of **last** here. The following template match should also work.

```
<xsl:template match="node[@name][last()]">
```

Comment: Thank you, didn't know about the `following-sibling` function.

Comment: @svz `following-sibling` is an _axis_, not a _function_. It may sound like I'm being pedantic but you need to know the right terms to be able to make sense of the documentation in future...

Comment: @IanRoberts, Thanks =) Actually, I'm not really familiar with XSL yet, so I find many things strange and confusing.

Comment: @svz indeed, xslt being a functional language requires quite a different mindset from more procedural or OO languages. It's worth persevering and getting comfortable with the template matching approach - avoid the temptation to slip back into `xsl:for-each` and `xsl:choose` if you can :-)

Answer (score 0):

You just used this code :

```
<xsl:template match="/node/[@name='3'][last()]">
```

Comment: Ok, but what if the @name is not `3`? =)

Comment: oXmlDocument.DocumentElement.LastChild.SelectSingleNode("name").Text

Comment: And once again, it's `XSL` =)